# Add multiple unknowns to a string in Pyton

Tags: python, string, loops

I need to add to the line:

```
url="items.point&point1={item}%2C{item}&point2C{item}%2C{item}"
```

four values ​​of possible coordinates instead of "item" value. We have to generate these coordinate values ​​in a loop.

I tried many different options for how to do this, but the program displays a lot of extra values.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
coordinates=[]
for item in np.arange(45.024287,45.024295,0.000001):
    coordinates.append("%.6f" %item)
    for item in np.arange(45.024287,45.024295,0.000001):
        coordinates.append("%.6f" %item)
urls=[]
for item in (coordinates):
    urls.append(f"items.point&point1{item}%2C{item}&point2={item}%2C{item}")
print(urls)
```

I need to get this result:

```
"items.point&point1=45.024295%2C45.024295&point2=39.073557%2C45.005125","items.point&point1=45.024294%2C45.024294&point2=39.073557%2C45.005125"...Etc
```

With different coordinates

But I am getting repeated values ​​due to the fact that the loop is in a loop.
Can you tell me how you can substitute several variables in a string without doubling the values?Please

Comment: I don't understand why you have nested loops. If you want the same `{item}` in both fields of `point1`, you can do with just one loop.

Comment: You're missing `=` between `point1` and `{item}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember reading recently something related to your problem. Can't remember the post, else I'd link it, but I took notes about the beautiful method! So try this:

```
urls=[]
for item1, item2 in zip(*[iter(coordinates)]*2):
    urls.append(f"items.point&point1{item1}%2C{item2}&point2=39.073557%2C45.005125")
print(urls)
```

Comment: or just `for coord in coordinates: ... {coord} ... {coord} ...`, seems like that would achieve the same thing, not sure if that's the thing to be achieved though

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the OP did?

Comment: Alright, this is actually pretty clever and cool

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought when I saw this "trick"; a similar way to do this would be: c=iter(coordinates) then replace item1 and item2 with next(c) and next(c).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the `coordinates` array. Just append to `urls` in the nested `for` loop to get all the combinations of item values.

```
for item1 in np.arange(45.024287,45.024295,0.000001):
    for item2 in np.arange(45.024287,45.024295,0.000001):
        urls.append(f"items.point&point1={item1}%2C{item2}&point2=39.073557%2C45.005125")
```